# Option with Label not found Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-ide

I have getting this error, on running script in Selenium IDE on Firefox.

```
[error] Option with label 'Morning' not found
```

Following link has image which shows the part of script which causes error on running this command.

[Script Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkyiD.png)

This error doesn't occur when the script run speed is set to medium speed. But I need to run it in fast speed mode. So what command to use so that the error gets removed in fast speed mode.

Comment: Instead of adding the image it's helpful to provide the command in text in the question

Answer (score 1):

It will fail on the faster speed as the element wont have fully loaded yet. Add in a waitForElementPresent step.

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=ddl_Shift</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>id=ddl_Shift</td>
    <td>label=morning</td>
</tr>
```

You could use a pause, but it's not the most efficient solution. For example if the website was slow to respond at any point it would still fail, and if you just set a long pause your script would take longer than needed if the element is fast to load. This way it only waits as long as it needs to.

Comment: Always use waitFor's instead of pauses unless testing something specific to  timing (check if pop up disappears after 10 seconds)

Answer (score -1):

Insert "pause" command before the "Morning" label check command.

```
Command      Target          Value

pause        3500
select       id=ddl_Shift    label=morning
```

you can increase the pause target and check.

refer these too

http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2012/11/pause-refresh-and-waitforpagetoload.html

For better solution refer below link. Other than using pause, below article explains how to use commands like "waitfor"

http://www.softwaretestingclub.com/profiles/blogs/selenium-ide-hints-intro-recording-waiting

Comment: Don't use pauses, it's bad technique: it adds a set amount of time to the test whereas the waitfor commands use only the time needed (up to a timeout) to wait.